# How can I generate a breadcrumb of Categories in pure MySQL?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

Say I have the mdl_course_categories table:

```
select cat.id, cat.name, cat.parent, cat.depth, cat.path
from mdl_course_categories cat
```

```
| id | name | parent | depth | path     |
|----|------|--------|-------|----------|
| 1  | a    | 0      | 1     | /1       |
| 2  | b    | 0      | 1     | /2       |
| 3  | c    | 1      | 2     | /1/3     |
| 4  | d    | 3      | 3     | /1/3/4   |
| 5  | e    | 4      | 4     | /1/3/4/5 |
| 6  | f    | 0      | 1     | /6       |
| 7  | g    | 6      | 2     | /6/7     |
| 8  | h    | 7      | 3     | /6/7/8   |
| 9  | i    | 3      | 3     | /1/3/9   |
| 10 | j    | 7      | 3     | /6/7/10  |
```

How can I generate the breadcrumbs as per below? I'm a complete rookie to SQL, and have no experience managing hierarchial data. I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1495547/4096963), but was unable to translate it to my table and situation. Thanks in advance!

```
| id | name | parent | depth | path     | breadcrumb    |
|----|------|--------|-------|----------|---------------|
| 1  | a    | 0      | 1     | /1       | a             |
| 2  | b    | 0      | 1     | /2       | b             |
| 3  | c    | 1      | 2     | /1/3     | a - c         |
| 4  | d    | 3      | 3     | /1/3/4   | a - c - d     |
| 5  | e    | 4      | 4     | /1/3/4/5 | a - c - d - e |
| 6  | f    | 0      | 1     | /6       | f             |
| 7  | g    | 6      | 2     | /6/7     | f - g         |
| 8  | h    | 7      | 3     | /6/7/8   | f - g - h     |
| 9  | i    | 3      | 3     | /1/3/9   | a - b - i     |
| 10 | j    | 7      | 3     | /6/7/10  | f - g - j     |
```

Comment: Pls share what you have tried and where you got stuck with your attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS 
(
SELECT 1 num
UNION ALL
SELECT num + 1
FROM cte1
WHERE num < ( SELECT MAX(LENGTH(path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(path, '/', '')))
              FROM mdl_course_categories )
),
cte2 AS 
(
SELECT cte1.num, 
       cat.*, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cat.path, '/', cte1.num+1), '/', -1) onechar
FROM cte1, mdl_course_categories cat
WHERE cte1.num <= (LENGTH(path) - LENGTH(REPLACE(cat.path, '/', '')))
),
cte3 AS 
(
SELECT cte2.*, cat.name onecharname
FROM cte2, mdl_course_categories cat
WHERE cte2.onechar = cat.id
)
SELECT id, name, parent, depth, path, GROUP_CONCAT(onecharname ORDER BY num SEPARATOR ' - ') breadcrumb
FROM cte3
GROUP BY id, name, parent, depth, path;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44f371bdca84cb6cdb000878e1974b65)

Of course it can be compacted, but I think you can do it by yourself.

---

At the request of [@Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389997/shadow) I also give a simple solution

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.name, 
       t1.parent, 
       t1.depth, 
       t1.path, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name ORDER BY LOCATE(CONCAT('/', t2.id, '/'), CONCAT(t1.path, '/')) SEPARATOR ' - ') breadcrumb
FROM mdl_course_categories t1, 
     mdl_course_categories t2
WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT('/', t2.id, '/'), CONCAT(t1.path, '/'))
GROUP BY t1.id, 
         t1.name, 
         t1.parent, 
         t1.depth, 
         t1.path;
```

PS. Remember, 1st is `O(N*AVG(M))` whereas 2nd is `O(N*N)` - where `N` is amount of records, and `M` is tree depth.

Comment: 1) The whole point of materialised path technique is to avoid recursion, so your solution kinda defeats the purpose of the whole technique. 2) A join and group_concat() can do all the above (yeah, the join will require full table scan)

Comment: @Shadow *The whole point of materialised path technique is to avoid recursion* The subtask solved by recursion is not relative to the materialised path technique and solves another task.

Comment: Yes, it is related to the underlying technique used. If you revert to recursion, then an adjancency list would be easier and faster, since you would not have to do expensive string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, @Akina! The simplified solution is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Say, if I only had the `name` of the category I wanted to filter on, how could I filter to only display the category `f` and it's sub-categories? 

i.e. shows `f`, `f - g`, `f - g - h`, and `f - g - j` in my example data.

Comment: @Zectzozda `WHERE LOCATE('f', value) = 1` or `WHERE value LIKE 'f%'`.

Comment: The 2nd version is not n*n problem, you are not creating a cartesian join. The condition in the where clause can be moved into the join condition (mysql optimiser will probably do that anyway).

Comment: @Shadow The condition does not allow index usage - so it is cartesian, fullscan will be used for calculate joining expression value for each separate records pair. *The condition in the where clause can be moved into the join condition (mysql optimiser will probably do that anyway).* Read "How MySQL optimizes joins" - everything is strongly backward.

Comment: Sorry to point out but in this case your solution is also n*n, since the recursive cte cannot use an index either to restrict the values from the underlying table.

Comment: @Shadow Recursive `cte1` does not need in a table in its recursion, and its subquery will be executed once (yes, using fullscan), it is O(N) and do not affect on the final complexity.

Comment: And then matched against without any indexes to the 2nd cte... Sorry man, not buying your argument.

Comment: Is there a way to re-write the `from` and `where` clause into a join? I've tried joining on the where clause, but it only shows the category name - no breadcrumb.

`from mdl_course_categories t1 join mdl_course_categories t2 on locate(concat('/', t2.id, '/'), concat(t1.path, '/')) = 1`

Comment: @Zectzozda Why `=1`? Where it is taken from? Simply `FROM mdl_course_categories t1 JOIN mdl_course_categories t2 ON LOCATE(CONCAT('/', t2.id, '/'), CONCAT(t1.path, '/'))`

Comment: D'Oh! I thought the join had to resolve to an `a = b`, so I used `= 1` to resolve as true. Thanks for fixing my blonde moment :)

Comment: @Zectzozda ON clause needs a value which may be treated as boolean. LOCATE() returns integer, which may - if NULL or zero, it is treated as FALSE, else it is treated as TRUE.

Comment: Anyone here so happens to know the SQL Server 2016 version of this? I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure it out!